# Directive with template thet contains few quotation marks iside each other

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an html component:

```
 <div style="width:500px;">
        <div ng-repeat="day in week" ng-class="{true:'possibleDayStyle', false:'notPossibleDay'}[day.selected]" ng-click="AddOrRemoveDay(day)">
            {{day.name}}</div>
        <button class="btnAddPossibleDays" ng-click="getAllSelectedDays()">Add</button>
    </div>
```

I want to extract this code to a directive.

```
app.directive("weekDays", function(){
  return{
    restrict: "AEC",
    replace: true,
    template: '<div style="width:500px;">'+
                '<div ng-repeat="day in week" ng-class="{true:"possibleDayStyle", false:"notPossibleDay"}[day.selected]" ng-click="AddOrRemoveDay(day)">'+
                    '{{day.name}}</div>'+
                '<button class="btnAddPossibleDays" ng-click="getAllSelectedDays()">Add</button>'+
                '</div>'
  }
});
```

But I have a problem with ng-class that contains quotation marks inside quotation marks inside quotation marks

I dont want to extract it to another html page using templateurl.
how can i solve it?

Comment: try    \'   inside ng-class to escape those quotes

Answer (score 0):

This is full sample

```js
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedDays = [];

  $scope.week = [{
    name: 1,
    selected: true
  }, {
    name: 2,
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 3,
    selected: true
  }, {
    name: 4,
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 5,
    selected: true
  }, {
    name: 6,
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 7,
    selected: false
  }];

  $scope.getAllSelectedDays = function() {
    $scope.selectedDays = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.week, function(day) {
      if (day.selected) {
        $scope.selectedDays.push(day);
      }
    });
    console.log($scope.selectedDays);
  }

});
angular.module("app").directive("weekDays", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "AEC",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      array: "=",
      action: "&"
    },
    template: "<div>" +
      "<div ng-repeat=\"day in array\" ng-class=\"day.selected ? 'possibleDayStyle':'notPossibleDay'\">" +
      "{{day.name}}" +
      "<button ng-click=\"addOrRemoveDay(day)\">{{day.selected ? 'remove':'add'}}</button>" +
      "</div> " +
      "<button ng-click=\"getAllSelectedDays()\">get All selected days</button>" +
      "</div>",
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.getAllSelectedDays = function() {
        scope.action();
      }

      scope.addOrRemoveDay = function(day) {
        day.selected ? day.selected = false : day.selected = true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
    .possibleDayStyle {
      background: blue;
    }
    .notPossibleDay {
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <week-days array="week" action="getAllSelectedDays()"></week-days>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check your browser console if you click on "get All Selected days".